# can't find android project template in intilij idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I use intellij-idea and when I click on the project new -} on this page, I don't see Android.

I tried several ways, but it didn't work, like installing a plugin and changing a series of settings, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### *Android Studio*

Google offers free-of-cost a special edition of [*IntelliJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) built specifically for Android development: [*Android Studio*](https://developer.android.com/studio).

### IntelliJ with plugins

According to [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-android-application.html), apparently you can do Android development if you install plugins for:

- [*Android*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22989-android)
- [*Android Design Studio*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22990-android-design-tools)